# How to find the first column in an ACCESS table row with a value not Zero of Blank?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which includes a column of each month (Jan-13, Feb-13, Mar-13, etc) for a period of four years. I need to find the first column in each row that has a value other than "0" (zero). Then I will need to find the last column with a value other than zero.

The query will let me know the start month and the end month of a resource. I have written an Excel formula but now I need to convert the same functionality to Access. When I find each of the columns I need to retrieve the column heading. Could anyone help me with the SQL for my query?

The report based on the query would be

```
ResourceName, StartDate EndDate
Bob Sample    Apr-13    Apr-15
```

There are actual two tables involved. The Resource table with all the information for the individuals and a forecast table which has the months as columns and the resource id and task for rows. For each month an individual is forecast to work a given percent of their time. We are not concerned about the actual dates (11/20/201) the individual starts, just the month. So a resource for task 1 is forecast to work .5 percent of their time in Nov-13, which would be the first month that the resource work. Then that resource may be forecast to work at the same level for the next nine months. So the column for Aug-14 would be the last month with the .5 value. After that all columns contains zeros.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, you would not store your data like this. Instead, you would have 2 tables:

1. Your resources
2. The months in which a resource does work (for a task)

**Example:**

*Table 1 resources:*

```
ID | Resource_Name
1  | Mr. A
2  | Mrs. B
```

*Table 2 Forecast:*

```
FC_ID | FC_Month   | FC_Resource_ID | FC_Task     | FC_Percentage
1     | 2013-10-01 | 1              | actiontask! | 0.05
2     | 2013-11-01 | 1              | actiontask! | 0.10
3     | 2013-12-01 | 1              | actiontask! | 0.05
4     | 2013-07-01 | 2              | boring task | 0.3
5     | 2013-08-01 | 2              | boring task | 0.25
6     | 2013-09-01 | 2              | boring task | 0.3
7     | 2013-10-01 | 2              | boring task | 0.1
```

You can then request the start and end date using SQL:

```
SELECT Resource_Name, Min(FC_Month) AS colMin, Max(FC_Month) As colMax 
FROM tblForecast INNER JOIN tblResources ON FC_Resource_ID=Resource_ID
GROUP BY FC_Resource_ID, Resource_Name
```

**The result of this example will be:**

```
Mr. A  | 2013-10-01 | 2013-12-01
Mrs. B | 2013-07-01 | 2013-10-01
```

Comment: Markus,  Thanks for the quick reply. Please see the additional information I added to my question.

Comment: @TerryTewell I read your add'l info and you can solve this exactly as I proposed. Table 1 would be your "Resource Table" and Table 2 would be your "Forecast Table". The only difference is that in the "Forecast Table", you would have 4 columns: ID, Date (aka Month), Resource_ID and Task. Each Resource/Task/Month-combination will take one row in the Forecast Table. Please do NOT create a table with months as columns. You will experience a constant need to add more columns (as time passes by) and this is hassle- & error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

(I will limit my example to six months because I'm lazy.)

So we have some "wide" data in a table named [Forecast]:

```
ResourceID  Jul-13  Aug-13  Sep-13  Oct-13  Nov-13  Dec-13
----------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------
         1       0     0.5       1     0.5       0       0
         2       0       0       2       0       0       0
         3       0       0       3       4       0       0
```

Start by creating a saved query in Access named [ForecastUnpivoted] to convert the "short wide" data into "long skinny" data:

```sql
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-07" AS forecastMonth, [Jul-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
UNION ALL
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-08" AS forecastMonth, [Aug-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
UNION ALL
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-09" AS forecastMonth, [Sep-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
UNION ALL
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-10" AS forecastMonth, [Oct-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
UNION ALL
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-11" AS forecastMonth, [Nov-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
UNION ALL
    SELECT ResourceID, "2013-12" AS forecastMonth, [Dec-13] AS forecastValue
    FROM Forecast
```

which returns

```
ResourceID  forecastMonth  forecastValue
----------  -------------  -------------
         1  2013-07                    0
         2  2013-07                    0
         3  2013-07                    0
         1  2013-08                  0.5
         2  2013-08                    0
         3  2013-08                    0
         1  2013-09                    1
         2  2013-09                    2
         3  2013-09                    3
         1  2013-10                  0.5
         2  2013-10                    0
         3  2013-10                    4
         1  2013-11                    0
         2  2013-11                    0
         3  2013-11                    0
         1  2013-12                    0
         2  2013-12                    0
         3  2013-12                    0
```

Now we can use Min() and Max() to give us the start end end dates for each resource

```sql
SELECT 
    ResourceID, 
    Min(forecastMonth) AS StartMonth, 
    Max(forecastMonth) AS EndMonth
FROM ForecastUnpivoted
WHERE forecastValue <> 0
GROUP BY ResourceID
```

That gives us

```
ResourceID  StartMonth  EndMonth
----------  ----------  --------
         1  2013-08     2013-10 
         2  2013-09     2013-09 
         3  2013-09     2013-10
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but you and I know that this is not a functional database structure in any way ;-)